# PL/SQL program using CURSOR for frequency distribution in table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, sql-insert

finaltableA has two columns WORDS, WCOUNTS. The program should insert every word of intitaltableA into finaltableA exactly once. In the column WCOUNTS the program should put how often the word occurs.

| intitaltableA |
| --- |
| COVID |
| is |
| a |
| disease |
| COVID |
| can |
| be |
| treated |
| with |
| antibodies |
| COVID |
| is |
| a |
| serious |
| disease |
| there |
| is |
| a |
| vaccination |
| available |
| for |
| COVID |

finaltableA should look like this -

| WORDS | WCOUNTS |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| antibodies | 1 |
| available | 1 |
| be | 1 |
| can | 1 |
| COVID | 4 |
| disease | 2 |
| for | 1 |
| is | 3 |
| serious | 1 |
| there | 1 |
| treated | 1 |
| vaccination | 1 |
| with | 1 |

I should use a cursor to insert and update the table. I am new to PL/SQL.

Comment: Since you say that you have to use a cursor, I assume this is a homework problem (real systems would just do a simple insert).  We're happy to help with homework but it's very hard to help unless you include what you've tried, what errors you're getting, what isn't working, etc.  Otherwise, we have to guess at what problems you're having.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite obvious that you can do this without any cursor in PLSQL, so I guess that means that you are trying to solve a homework problem or a training question. Anyway, here you can see two simple options to get the result you want, with and without PLSQL.

**Option 1 - Without PLSQL**

```
with x ( words ) 
as 
( 
select 'COVID'        from dual union all
select 'is'           from dual union all
select 'a'            from dual union all
select 'disease'      from dual union all
select 'COVID'        from dual union all
select 'can'          from dual union all
select 'be'           from dual union all
select 'treated'      from dual union all
select 'with'         from dual union all
select 'antibodies'   from dual union all
select 'COVID'        from dual union all
select 'is'           from dual union all
select 'a'            from dual union all
select 'serious'      from dual union all
select 'disease'      from dual union all
select 'there'        from dual union all
select 'is'           from dual union all
select 'a'            from dual union all
select 'vaccination'  from dual union all
select 'available'    from dual union all
select 'for'          from dual union all
select 'COVID'        from dual 
)
select words, count(words) as counter 
from x
group by words
order by 2 desc;
```

If you execute it, it gives you the output you want

```
SQL> with x ( words )
  2  as
  3  (
  4  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
  5  select 'is'           from dual union all
  6  select 'a'            from dual union all
  7  select 'disease'      from dual union all
  8  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
  9  select 'can'          from dual union all
 10  select 'be'           from dual union all
 11  select 'treated'      from dual union all
 12  select 'with'         from dual union all
 13  select 'antibodies'   from dual union all
 14  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
 15  select 'is'           from dual union all
 16  select 'a'            from dual union all
 17  select 'serious'      from dual union all
 18  select 'disease'      from dual union all
 19  select 'there'        from dual union all
 20  select 'is'           from dual union all
 21  select 'a'            from dual union all
 22  select 'vaccination'  from dual union all
 23  select 'available'    from dual union all
 24  select 'for'          from dual union all
 25  select 'COVID'        from dual
 26  )
 27  select words, count(words) as counter
 28  from x
 29  group by words
 30* order by 2 desc
SQL> /

WORDS          COUNTER
----------- ----------
COVID                4
is                   3
a                    3
disease              2
there                1
available            1
for                  1
serious              1
antibodies           1
can                  1
vaccination          1

WORDS          COUNTER
----------- ----------
treated              1
be                   1
with                 1

14 rows selected.
```

**Option 2 - Using PLSQL and a CURSOR**

In the below example, I'm going to use `dbms_output` to show the results. Keep in mind that here there are dozens of ways to do the same, I am just using the simplest one I can think of.

```
SQL> create table t ( words varchar2(40) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  with x ( words )
  3  as
  4  (
  5  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
  6  select 'is'           from dual union all
  7  select 'a'            from dual union all
  8  select 'disease'      from dual union all
  9  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
 10  select 'can'          from dual union all
 11  select 'be'           from dual union all
 12  select 'treated'      from dual union all
 13  select 'with'         from dual union all
 14  select 'antibodies'   from dual union all
 15  select 'COVID'        from dual union all
 16  select 'is'           from dual union all
 17  select 'a'            from dual union all
 18  select 'serious'      from dual union all
 19  select 'disease'      from dual union all
 20  select 'there'        from dual union all
 21  select 'is'           from dual union all
 22  select 'a'            from dual union all
 23  select 'vaccination'  from dual union all
 24  select 'available'    from dual union all
 25  select 'for'          from dual union all
 26  select 'COVID'        from dual
 27* ) select words from x
SQL> /

22 rows created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL>  declare
  2  begin
  3  for i in ( select words, count(words) as counter from t group by words order by 2 desc )
  4  loop
  5     dbms_output.put_line( 'Words: '||i.words||' - Wcount is: '||i.counter||' ');
  6  end loop;
  7* end;
SQL> /
Words: COVID - Wcount is: 4
Words: is - Wcount is: 3
Words: a - Wcount is: 3
Words: disease - Wcount is: 2
Words: antibodies - Wcount is: 1
Words: for - Wcount is: 1
Words: be - Wcount is: 1
Words: vaccination - Wcount is: 1
Words: can - Wcount is: 1
Words: available - Wcount is: 1
Words: treated - Wcount is: 1
Words: there - Wcount is: 1
Words: with - Wcount is: 1
Words: serious - Wcount is: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```